# Full duplex Audio With USB Sound Card

Tags: raspbian, audio

I setup Raspberry Pi with external usb sound blaster sound card. My Goal is to be able to record and play audio simultaneously. I setup and configured it to be the default sound card as follows:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo apt-get install rpi-update`
4. `sudo rpi-update`
5. Modified `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
    and added the following to force the default sound module (`snd_bcm2835`) to be disabled while the usb sound module (`snd-usb-audio`) is enabled 
                    `options snd-usb-audio index=0`
                    `options snd_bcm2835   index=1`
6. Tested the sound card by playing file audio using `aplay soundFile.wav`

   To test the full duplex i used the following simple java program that read and play audio kinda of a loopback  with different Audio formats but no audio heard.

   import java.io.*;
   import javax.sound.sampled.*;

   ```
    public class test1
   {
        public static void main(String[] args)
       {
        AudioFormat pcmAF =new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1,true, true);//new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1,false, false);

             //new AudioFormat(8000f,16,1,true,true);
             //new AudioFormat(8000f,16,1,true,true)
            //new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16000.0f, 16, 1, 2, 16000.0f, true);  
            // new AudioFormat(24000f,8,1,true,true);
            // new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16000.0f, 16, 1, 2, 16000.0f, true);
           ///new AudioFormat(8000f,16,1,true,true);
           // new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1,true, true);//11025
          try
               {
           DataLine.Info info = new
                       DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,pcmAF);
           TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
           targetLine.open(pcmAF);
           targetLine.start();

           DataLine.Info info1 = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,pcmAF);
           SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info1);
           sourceLine.open(pcmAF);
            sourceLine.start();
           byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
           int bytesRead;

           while (true)

           {
              System.out.println("READING  SOUND ");
               bytesRead = targetLine.read(buf,0,buf.length);
               System.out.println("->"+ bytesRead);
               sourceLine.write(buf,0,bytesRead);
           }
       }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                 {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       System.exit(0);
   }
   }
   ```

   Any idea why and what need to be done to achieve that ?

Comment: Do you specifically want to play/record simultaneously in Java, or just in general on the Pi. Have you tried `arecord` and `aplay` simultaneously? `alsaloop` can be used to loop input to output on a sound card.